# Bypass a specific parent node when deserializing XML?

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

Assuming the following XML:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <B1>b1Value</B1>
        <B2>b2Value</B2>
        <B3>b3Value</B3>
    </B>
    <C Attr="val1"/>
    <C Attr="val2"/>
    <C Attr="val3"/>
</A>
```

And the following desired deserialization classes:

```
public class C
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Attr { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot]
public class A
{
    [XmlElement("C")]
    public C[] Cs { get; set; }
    public string B1 { get; set; }
    public string B2 { get; set; }
    public string B3 { get; set; }
}
```

How can I deserialize the XML in order for my A class to have the properties B1, B2 and B3, without having a parent property B?

When I use this code:

```
string xml =
@"<A>
    <B>
        <B1>b1Value</B1>
        <B2>b2Value</B2>
        <B3>b3Value</B3>
    </B>
    <C Attr=""val1""/>
    <C Attr=""val2""/>
    <C Attr=""val3""/>
</A>";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A));
A a;

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    a = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as A;
}
```

all the BX properties are blank.

[dotnetfiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aeEAhd),

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add read-only properties to access the data on the level you want.

```
public class C
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Attr { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string B1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string B2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string B3 { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot]
public class A
{
    [XmlElement("C")]
    public C[] Cs { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("B")]
    public B B { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public string B1 => B?.B1;
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public string B2 => B?.B2;
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public string B3 => B?.B3;
}
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tv8vH2)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one of the class B. B Class has Elements within it that you are looking to obtain. You will need to use the classes like this,

You cannot deserialize the xml you have without using the B as the parent class. Since B1, B2 and B3 are part of the element B, you have to use the structure in your C# to match it. Each of the element you have within the B element have different names as well.

```
public class C
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Attr { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string B1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string B2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string B3 { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot]
public class A
{
    [XmlElement("C")]
    public C[] Cs { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("B")]
    public B B { get; set; }
}
```

and in the main, you would deserialize it like the way you already are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XElement to parse instead:

```
string xml =
    @"<A>
        <B>
            <B1>b1Value</B1>
            <B2>b2Value</B2>
            <B3>b3Value</B3>
        </B>
        <C Attr=""val1""/>
        <C Attr=""val2""/>
        <C Attr=""val3""/>
    </A>";

XElement xe = XElement.Parse(xml);

A a = new A()
{
  Cs = xe.Elements("C").Select(a => new C() { Attr = a.Attribute("Attr").Value }).ToArray(),
  B1 = (string)xe.Element("B").Element("B1"),
  B2 = (string)xe.Element("B").Element("B2"),
  B3 = (string)xe.Element("B").Element("B3")
};
```